# DBMS_PARALLEL_EXECUTE.run_task doesn't start parallel jobs

Tags: oracle, parallel-processing

I want to run my procedure in parallel so I use `DBMS_PARALLEL_EXECUTE` package. However, I'm facing a problem on one instance and the problem is that my jobs don't start. Session waits on `PL/SQL Lock Timer` event and nothing happens. Parameter `job_queue_processes` is set to `64`. I set `parallel_level` param to `NULL` to let Oracle set degree of parallelism but it didn't help.

I'm on `Oracle 11gR2`, Single instance.

Questions:
 - Are there any tricks to check if this approach doesn't meet any requirements? Maybe some `user_*` views?
 - Maybe there are some running jobs that "consume" my `job_queue_processes`?

My code snippet:

```
DECLARE
  l_task_name VARCHAR2(100) := 'update_data';
  l_splitter  VARCHAR2(4000) := '
select level, level from dual connect by level <= 16';
  l_exec_stmt VARCHAR2(1000) := 'begin update_data(:start_id, :end_id); end;';
BEGIN
  FOR line IN (SELECT d.task_name
                 FROM user_parallel_execute_tasks d
                WHERE d.task_name = l_task_name)
  LOOP
    dbms_parallel_execute.drop_task(task_name => line.task_name);
  END LOOP;

  dbms_parallel_execute.create_task(l_task_name);
  dbms_parallel_execute.create_chunks_by_sql(task_name => l_task_name
                                            ,sql_stmt  => l_splitter
                                            ,by_rowid  => FALSE);

  dbms_parallel_execute.run_task(l_task_name
                                ,l_exec_stmt
                                ,dbms_sql.native
                                ,parallel_level => NULL);

  COMMIT;

END;
/
```

Comment: Did you check if you have any warning or message in the alert log ?

Comment: Do you call `DBMS_LOCK.SLEEP` in `update_data` ? You can query currently running DBMS_SCHEDULER jobs using  `select session_id, job_id from V$SCHEDULER_RUNNING_JOBS;`.

Comment: Your code above is good, just used on a fake update_data proc and it worked. So probably the problem comes from your stored procedure. Are you sure it can run in parallel?

Comment: You can get `PL/SQL lock timer` waits if parameter `job_queue_processes` is too low, although 64 should be OK if you have only 16 parallel jobs - it depends on what else is running ...

Comment: Thank you guys! The problem is that database is in PROD and I don't have any access to check stuff. I asked our DBAs for `alert.log` (thanks to @pifor). And I guess that someone is using my `job_queue_processes` limit. But how can one query that?

Comment: Querying `dba_scheduler_running_jobs` should give all information about DBMS_SCHEDULER running jobs.

Comment: I got `alert.log` and it doesn't contain any messages connected with jobs. Tomorrow we will do another run so I will try to check `dba_scheduler_running_jobs`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally DBAs told me that in the end my jobs started and worked successfully.

So the answer is based on recommendations from comments:

- Check your `job_queue_processes` DB parameter to see if jobs are allowed to start;
- Check running scheduler jobs via `dba_scheduler_running_jobs` or `v$scheduler_running_jobs` to look for jobs that "consume" your `job_queue_processes` parameter and don't let your process start;
- Check `alert.log` of your database to see if something unforeseen happened to your database.

Also keep in mind [Doc ID 1916579.1](https://support.oracle.com/epmos/faces/DocumentDisplay?_afrLoop=209049193151179&id=1916579.1&_afrWindowMode=0&_adf.ctrl-state=b7dmsesde_4). This doc states that there is a degradation when running `DBMS_PARALLEL_EXECUTE` jobs on unpatched Oracle DB. Even this bug is very old (Basic 12.2.0.1.0 has fixes on it) consider checking if it is installed on your instance.